# Using a DC / DC Converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, 5v, 3.3v, launchpad

I'm trying to use a MAX541 DAC (datasheet [here](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX541-MAX542.pdf)) with a Tiva LaunchPad (TM4C123G).  I've gotten this to work with other DACs, the problem is that that those DACs required 3.3 volts and the MAX541 requires 5 volts.

The Tiva LaunchPad outputs 3.3V.  I've purchased [this](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/468/ROE-766139.pdf) RECOM ROE-3.305S DC/DC Converter which is supposed to convert 3.3V to 5V.  However, when using it with the 3.3V input, it's outputting 6.35 volts and not the 5 volts that I need.

The DC/DC converter simply has four pins that plug into a breadboard: -Vin, +Vin, -Vout, +Vout.  I simply plug the ground of the Tiva LaunchPad to the -Vin.  The 3.3V power from the Tiva LaunchPad to the +Vin.  Still I get 6.35V and not 5volts.  Am I doing something wrong?  Anyone?

Comment: Can you share the schematics section including regulator. Capacitors and any other load connected?

Comment: Also, where do you measure 6.35V?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the DC/DC converter module requires a minimum load.  Notice that the regulation is specified for 20% to 100% load.  But the datasheet doesn't say what happens when load is less than 20%.

You can check this hypothesis, connect a 100Ω dummy load resistor (it should be rated for 0.25W or more), and measure the output voltage.

[image: datasheet snippet] (source: p.2 in the [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/468/ROE-766139.pdf))